# Redirect in Django admin page

Tags: django, redirect

In my django project, after activating the admin application, I canno't get access to the page localhost/soundaxis/admin because I'm redirected to localhost/admin.

I think the problem has to do with the fact that the project was not located at the base address.

**Urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^soundaxis/', 'views.index.home'),
     (r'^soundaxis/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Can we see your urls.py?

Comment: Of course. I edited the question and see there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the server by typing the following in the base dir:
    python manage.py runserver

then go to http://localhost:8000/

Its rather complicated to get the project to run off another subdirectory so I suggest running it from the base, especially during development. Later in the game you can try work it from a subdir if required, but better yet would be subdomain.